# How to return value from function in scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I am running the following code:

```
(define (myadd x y)
    (+ x y)
    (display (+ x y))
)

(define (mymul x y)
    (* x y)
    (display (* x y))
)

(apply myadd '(3 (apply mymul '(3 4)))
```

I am trying to get the answer 12 when I run `(apply myadd '(3 (apply mymul '(3 4)))` but instead I am getting the following error:

Error: +: number required, but got (apply mymul (quote (3 4))) [apply, (anon), +]

Answer (score 5):

A function returns the value of the last expression. So you need to end the function with the calculation. Put the `display` call first.

```
(define (myadd x y)
    (display (+ x y))
    (+ x y)
)
```

Also, you're not calling the functions correctly later. It should be:

```
(myadd 3 (mymul 3 4))
```

If you want to use `apply`, you need to make the list contain the result of calling the function. If you quote the whole list, it's just a literal, nothing is called.

```
(apply myadd (list 3 (apply mymul '(3 4)))
```